# setState() in render function return?

Tags: state, render, react-native

```
this.state = {
      fontLoading: false,
      dataFetched: false,
    };
```

I have two states which fontloading is changing inside async componentDidMount() and dataFetched is changing inside another function. 'fontLoading' is changing in below function.

```
async componentDidMount () {
    try {
      await Font.loadAsync ({
       ...
      });
      this.setState ({fontLoading: true});
    } catch (error) {
      ...
    }
}
```

First if and else if work fine with fontLoading and dataFetched. In last else condition screen is rendered for a second, than I got an error, because I am trying to change dataFatched state when Button is clicked. Render function again renders the View inside 'else if' condition after a second. But I want to render else condition and when I click the button I have to get else if return.

```
render(){
    if (!this.state.fontLoading) {
      return (<ActivityIndicator />);
    }
    else if (!this.state.dataFetched) {
      return (new<View>)
    }
    else {
      return (
      <View>
        <Button title = 'Click' onPress={this.setState({dataFetched: false});}></Button>
      </View>
     );
    }
```

I have not a certain knowledge of setting states inside render functions. What should I do to accomplish this certain task? Learning this here will increase my learning flow because rendering inside same component with state changes both encourages how to use states and what makes react-native beautiful I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have the `onPress` attribute written will end up calling `this.setState({dataFetched: false})` right away when the component is rendered.  `onPress` should be given a function as an argument, and that function should call `setState`.

```
onPress={this.setState({dataFetched: false});} // <- Replace this

onPress={() => this.setState({dataFetched: false})} // <- with this
```

Comment: Thank You for fast response @Eugene Pawlik. It works.